# xml serialization of double

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

when i serialize my object, my double value gets printed as -9.9999999999988987E-05
How can i fix this so i can get a number with 4 decimal places?

```
public class DecisionBar
    {
    public DateTime bartime 
         { get; set; }
    public string frequency
             { get; set; }
    public bool HH7
            {get;set;}
    public bool crossover
            {get;set;}
    public double mfe
            {get;set;}
        public double mae
            {get;set;}
                public double currentprofitability
            {get;set;}
    public double entryPointLong
            {get;set;}
    public double entryPointShort
            {get;set;}
    public double exitStopFull
            {get;set;}
    public double exitStopPartial 
                {get;set;}
     [XmlAttribute]         
    public string EntryOrExit
                {get;set;}
//    public DecisionBar()
//          {
//          crossover =false;
//          }

    }
```

Output.

```
<DecisionBar>
    <bartime>2012-07-24T08:59:00</bartime>
    <frequency>1 MINUTES</frequency>
    <HH7>false</HH7>
    <crossover>false</crossover>
    <mfe>0.00019999999999997797</mfe>
    <mae>-9.9999999999988987E-05</mae>
    <currentprofitability>0</currentprofitability>
    <entryPointLong>0</entryPointLong>
    <entryPointShort>0</entryPointShort>
    <exitStopFull>0</exitStopFull>
    <exitStopPartial>0</exitStopPartial>
</DecisionBar>
```

Comment: What is your actual double value, -10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Round value in get, so during serialization serializer read rounded values.

```
double _mfe;
double _mae;
        public double mfe
        {
             get
             {
                return Math.Round((decimal)_mfe, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
             }
             set
             {
                 _mfe = value;
             }
        }

        public double mae
        {
             get
             {
                return Math.Round((decimal)_mae, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
             }
             set
             {
                 _mae= value;
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can round the double before serializing it using

```
mfe = Math.Round(mfe, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

To automate this you can make mark the actual property with the `[XmlIgnore]` attribute and create new property that returns the rounded value.

I would recommend not to use a private field and `get; set;` accessors because the getter will round the property each time instead of only when serializing.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of possibly only rounding during serialization. However, this is a case to case basis, and it may actually be better for the OP to round even during construction.

Answer (score 0):

you can format the double at 4 decimal

```
double number = 123.64612312313;
number = double.Parse(number.ToString("####0.0000"));
```

Comment: Double casting is not the best solution in this case. Math.round is better suited.